# C# MSSQL retrieved string through reader is not equal with currently inputed word because 1 quote(") is missing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader, reader

In user registration window, I compare whether there is same ID in Server as we know very well.

It worked before but strangely not working now because
`(retrieved string) reader["userid"]= "greennature`   <----- 1 quote(") missing than below
`(inputed text now) textBoxGR1.Text= "greennature"`

There's only 1 missing quote(") at the end of retrieved string through reader.
So, the if statement return false(above 2 string are not same).

It worked before and I cannot understand why it's not working because of above reason..

Please kindly advice. Thank you !

```
if (reader.Read())
{

    if (reader["userid"].ToString() == textBoxGR1.Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("someone is using this ID already. Please try another ID");
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: can I state the obvious? The strings are not the same BECAUSE THEY ARE NOT THE SAME. Someone obviously was putting them into the database. A missing quote is a difference.

Comment: Can you check, what value is stored in the database? And you could also check the datatype to see if the database can store all the characters.

Comment: The quotes are added by the debugger when you look at a string value. They are not really present in your database value. The fact the you don't see the ending quote let me think that you have spaces (a lot of them) after the word. Try trimmering the returned value and tell us what is the datatype of the column. Varchar vs char, nvarchar vs nchar could be at the origin of the problem.

Comment: Solved) So many thanks to you all..I've just solved by myself right after writing this question..I've recently made new table and by mistake I made column as nchar which has to be nvarchar..But GvS and Steve were also right brilliantly ! My biggest appreciation to you all. Thank you so much !